# mdadm drive UUIDs chanaged, can they be changed back?

Tags: raid, software-raid, mdadm, ubuntu-12.04

So I ran into this trouble and I believe I lost all my data..However I found an old mdadm --examine --scan file I made a month ago and an old mdadm.conf....Is it possible to use these two items to fix my broken array??

What I have done so far is in the link [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/460129/mdadm-rebooted-array-missing-cant-assemble).

Here are the old mdadm --examine I found..

```
/dev/sdb1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : cbb5f346:fedb78ad:d8f6cdb7:18c42e5a
           Name : mediaserver:0  (local to host mediaserver)
  Creation Time : Thu Jun 21 01:23:41 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 16

 Avail Dev Size : 1953521072 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
     Array Size : 13674644480 (13041.16 GiB 14002.84 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953520640 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 99a146bf:615aa430:a443ec21:2841e82a

    Update Time : Mon Oct 22 19:39:22 2012
       Checksum : e94592f5 - correct
         Events : 7185

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 4
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdc1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : cbb5f346:fedb78ad:d8f6cdb7:18c42e5a
           Name : mediaserver:0  (local to host mediaserver)
  Creation Time : Thu Jun 21 01:23:41 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 16

 Avail Dev Size : 1953521072 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
     Array Size : 13674644480 (13041.16 GiB 14002.84 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953520640 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 934e400e:fc960419:50006e6f:c48e29de

    Update Time : Mon Oct 22 19:39:22 2012
       Checksum : 216286d6 - correct
         Events : 7185

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 5
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdd1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : cbb5f346:fedb78ad:d8f6cdb7:18c42e5a
           Name : mediaserver:0  (local to host mediaserver)
  Creation Time : Thu Jun 21 01:23:41 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 16

 Avail Dev Size : 1953521072 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
     Array Size : 13674644480 (13041.16 GiB 14002.84 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953520640 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : bf5290df:55168dfd:f5761d14:16ce5786

    Update Time : Mon Oct 22 19:39:22 2012
       Checksum : 2418c04c - correct
         Events : 7185

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sde1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : cbb5f346:fedb78ad:d8f6cdb7:18c42e5a
           Name : mediaserver:0  (local to host mediaserver)
  Creation Time : Thu Jun 21 01:23:41 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 16

 Avail Dev Size : 1953521072 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
     Array Size : 13674644480 (13041.16 GiB 14002.84 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953520640 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 70119dc9:198e057c:f5f6cf1f:0b11e24b

    Update Time : Mon Oct 22 19:39:22 2012
       Checksum : 5ddab9b6 - correct
         Events : 7185

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdf1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : cbb5f346:fedb78ad:d8f6cdb7:18c42e5a
           Name : mediaserver:0  (local to host mediaserver)
  Creation Time : Thu Jun 21 01:23:41 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 16

 Avail Dev Size : 1953521072 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
     Array Size : 13674644480 (13041.16 GiB 14002.84 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953520640 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : cf0d89d8:f272d1ee:3f123a4f:dd313ca1

    Update Time : Mon Oct 22 19:39:22 2012
       Checksum : 6456d70c - correct
         Events : 7185

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdg1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : cbb5f346:fedb78ad:d8f6cdb7:18c42e5a
           Name : mediaserver:0  (local to host mediaserver)
  Creation Time : Thu Jun 21 01:23:41 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 16

 Avail Dev Size : 1953521072 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
     Array Size : 13674644480 (13041.16 GiB 14002.84 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953520640 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : c6ec4433:f2fe4fd2:a19251b7:ffd6d6df

    Update Time : Mon Oct 22 19:39:22 2012
       Checksum : 49436788 - correct
         Events : 7185

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 3
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdh1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : cbb5f346:fedb78ad:d8f6cdb7:18c42e5a
           Name : mediaserver:0  (local to host mediaserver)
  Creation Time : Thu Jun 21 01:23:41 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 16

 Avail Dev Size : 1953521072 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
     Array Size : 13674644480 (13041.16 GiB 14002.84 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953520640 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : dd8f1c4f:edd28a32:bf20bf87:8106cee7

    Update Time : Mon Oct 22 19:39:22 2012
       Checksum : 9dba9c3c - correct
         Events : 7185

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 6
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdi1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : cbb5f346:fedb78ad:d8f6cdb7:18c42e5a
           Name : mediaserver:0  (local to host mediaserver)
  Creation Time : Thu Jun 21 01:23:41 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 16

 Avail Dev Size : 1953521072 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
     Array Size : 13674644480 (13041.16 GiB 14002.84 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953520640 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 4f5cc0c5:67df25a7:bea5d1ae:adaf0234

    Update Time : Mon Oct 22 19:39:22 2012
       Checksum : fc40a352 - correct
         Events : 7185

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 7
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdj1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : cbb5f346:fedb78ad:d8f6cdb7:18c42e5a
           Name : mediaserver:0  (local to host mediaserver)
  Creation Time : Thu Jun 21 01:23:41 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 16

 Avail Dev Size : 1953521072 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
     Array Size : 13674644480 (13041.16 GiB 14002.84 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953520640 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : e9329121:97ef3ec6:da2d3cc6:ea4829f6

    Update Time : Mon Oct 22 19:39:22 2012
       Checksum : 50bbab87 - correct
         Events : 7185

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 13
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdk1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : cbb5f346:fedb78ad:d8f6cdb7:18c42e5a
           Name : mediaserver:0  (local to host mediaserver)
  Creation Time : Thu Jun 21 01:23:41 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 16

 Avail Dev Size : 1953521072 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
     Array Size : 13674644480 (13041.16 GiB 14002.84 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953520640 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 91d46355:6d3655b5:b1826dad:b14a22f3

    Update Time : Mon Oct 22 19:39:22 2012
       Checksum : 57ceea9e - correct
         Events : 7185

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 10
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdl1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : cbb5f346:fedb78ad:d8f6cdb7:18c42e5a
           Name : mediaserver:0  (local to host mediaserver)
  Creation Time : Thu Jun 21 01:23:41 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 16

 Avail Dev Size : 1953521072 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
     Array Size : 13674644480 (13041.16 GiB 14002.84 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953520640 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 4896f6d1:ca2e1dd7:08c26d07:44c3086c

    Update Time : Mon Oct 22 19:39:22 2012
       Checksum : c9105ca1 - correct
         Events : 7185

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 15
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdm1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : cbb5f346:fedb78ad:d8f6cdb7:18c42e5a
           Name : mediaserver:0  (local to host mediaserver)
  Creation Time : Thu Jun 21 01:23:41 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 16

 Avail Dev Size : 1953521072 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
     Array Size : 13674644480 (13041.16 GiB 14002.84 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953520640 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 0e757d5e:9e1ee6f0:a37f1877:a030acb2

    Update Time : Mon Oct 22 19:39:22 2012
       Checksum : 25ae5631 - correct
         Events : 7185

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 14
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdn1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : cbb5f346:fedb78ad:d8f6cdb7:18c42e5a
           Name : mediaserver:0  (local to host mediaserver)
  Creation Time : Thu Jun 21 01:23:41 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 16

 Avail Dev Size : 1953521072 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
     Array Size : 13674644480 (13041.16 GiB 14002.84 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953520640 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 04bf5f29:6756326f:84101b6c:2f2c62d8

    Update Time : Mon Oct 22 19:39:22 2012
       Checksum : 8995645c - correct
         Events : 7185

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 9
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdo1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : cbb5f346:fedb78ad:d8f6cdb7:18c42e5a
           Name : mediaserver:0  (local to host mediaserver)
  Creation Time : Thu Jun 21 01:23:41 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 16

 Avail Dev Size : 1953521072 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
     Array Size : 13674644480 (13041.16 GiB 14002.84 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953520640 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : ebabf0a8:c330157b:ff450cb8:154f5401

    Update Time : Mon Oct 22 19:39:22 2012
       Checksum : 89ec8402 - correct
         Events : 7185

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 11
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdp1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : cbb5f346:fedb78ad:d8f6cdb7:18c42e5a
           Name : mediaserver:0  (local to host mediaserver)
  Creation Time : Thu Jun 21 01:23:41 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 16

 Avail Dev Size : 1953521072 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
     Array Size : 13674644480 (13041.16 GiB 14002.84 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953520640 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : e17c9f14:368fc642:6ec5e3d6:2b49925c

    Update Time : Mon Oct 22 19:39:22 2012
       Checksum : 37622cef - correct
         Events : 7185

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 12
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdq1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : cbb5f346:fedb78ad:d8f6cdb7:18c42e5a
           Name : mediaserver:0  (local to host mediaserver)
  Creation Time : Thu Jun 21 01:23:41 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 16

 Avail Dev Size : 1953521072 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
     Array Size : 13674644480 (13041.16 GiB 14002.84 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953520640 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 298efb40:36e48eae:4f87c7bc:559290fa

    Update Time : Mon Oct 22 19:39:22 2012
       Checksum : 53689e40 - correct
         Events : 7185

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 8
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
```

and here is the old mdadm.conf

mdadm.conf

```
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADD myemail@gmail.com

# definitions of existing MD arrays

# This file was auto-generated on Thu, 21 Jun 2012 01:11:03 -0400
# by mkconf $Id$

#definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 name=mediaserver:0 UUID=3591cbdb-01af-4b50-8cd9-206b02893fa7:18c42e5a
```

The current mdadm --examine I did for each drive shows now a different UUID?

```
Array UUID : 1c0d0df7:d321d9aa:1c920da2:2baa5067
```

The last thing I did before trying to troubleshoot was issue apt-get update and upgrade, then rebooted.

Thank you all!

Comment: Can you provide more detail about what trouble you ran into?  What happened to get the array into this state?

Comment: I ran apt-get update && apt-get upgrade...and rebooted. Using Ubuntu 12.04.1 server edition...